# Ansible Strange conditional behavior

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm facing a strange issue while trying to search inside a dictionary. In the code above, i'm trying to define a new var "OLD_VLANID_PP", with the value of the "name" key of the dictionary "VM_NETWORK_INFOS_PP".

If the dictionary is set and not empty, I want the var to be defined, otherwise just skip the task.
In order to test if the condition was true or false, I've added a debug task which should display the content of the dictionary.

When running my playbook, the debug task does indicates that the condition is not matched, and so doesn't display my dictionary, but Ansible keep trying to define my new var as shown in the output, and so fires an error "**'item' is undefined**"

```
---
- block:
      #Search VCENTER for PPROD VM (If Windows to create => Search PG / EIther search Postgre)
    - name: Search for PPROD VM already created for the CLIENT {{ CLIENTNAME }} to retrieve VLANID
      set_fact:
        OLD_VMNAME_PP: "{{ item.guest_name }}"
      with_items: "{{ VM_EXIST_PP.virtual_machines }}"
      when: item.guest_name == VMNAME_PP
      delegate_to: localhost

  when: ENV != "PROD" and DEPLOY != "ALL" and (VM_EXIST_PP is defined) and (VM_EXIST_PP|length > 0)

#If we successfully found the previous VM for the client, then get its network info
- name: Retrieve PPROD VM {{ VMNAME_PP }} VLAN ID
  community.vmware.vmware_guest_network:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_server }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
    validate_certs: False
    name: "{{ OLD_VMNAME_PP }}"
    gather_network_info: true
  register: VM_NETWORK_INFOS_PP
  when: (OLD_VMNAME_PP is defined) and OLD_VMNAME_PP != ""

- block:
  
    - debug: msg={{VM_NETWORK_INFOS_PP}}

    #If we successfully found the network info, set the OLD_VLANID with previous VM VLANID
    - set_fact:
        OLD_VLANID_PP: "{{ (item.name) | replace('(HDS : Client)','') | replace('VLAN0','') | replace('VLAN','') | replace(' ','') }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ VM_NETWORK_INFOS_PP.network_info }}"
      when: item.name | regex_search('VLAN') and not item.name | regex_search('PVLAN')


  when: (VM_NETWORK_INFOS_PP is defined) and VM_NETWORK_INFOS_PP != ""
```

Debug Output (Should display the dictionary content) :

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
        "skipped": true
    }
}
```

Error Output :

```
The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.name | regex_search('VLAN') and not item.name | regex_search('PVLAN')): 'item' is undefined
```

Ansible Version : 2.10.7
Python Version : 3.7.3

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is the output of your first `debug` task (`debug: msg={{VM_NETWORK_INFOS_PP}}`)?

Comment: Check my post, I already pasted it

Comment: Right now it's not running because of the `when` statement on your `block`. Move the `debug` statement out of the block so that we can see the content of the `VM_NETWORK_INFOS_PP` variable. It looks as if the variable is in fact not defined.

Comment: thank you for your help, I just edited the post to display the whole code and tasks. The last when statement is precisely here to check or not if  VM_NETWORK_INFOS_PP is defined and avoid this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the right thing to do, but finally get ride of this issue using :

```
when: item is defined and item.name | regex_search('VLAN') and not item.name | regex_search('PVLAN')
```

note the **item is defined** before the regex search